# how to link multiple alarmManagers with different notifications in OnReceive?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I want to fire different notifications when a specific alarmManager is reached.

For example I want to display "independence day" when we reach the date of Independence stored in a certain alarmManager, and to display "Steve jobs died" when we reach the date of his death stored in another Alarm Manager, and so on.

So my question is how to link each alarmManager(cal and cal2) with different notification?

I did this until now,

in MainActivity:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DATE,19);  
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);  
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21); 
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 42);       
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(Calendar.DATE,19);  
cal2.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);  
cal2.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);  
cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);     
cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);


Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

notice that I made to dates to fire notification and it is working, the notification in `onReceive` was fired twice, the first time when I reach "cal" and for the second time when I reach "cal2". But as I mentioned above, I need to fire a different notification when I reach cal2

this is the OnReceive:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     createNotification(context, "title1", "independence day", "event of today");
       //here i want to link this notification with AlarmManager containing Cal as a date
        createNotification(context, "title2", "steve jobs died", "event of today");
        //here i want to link this notification with AlarmManager containing Cal2 as a date




    }

    public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert) {
        PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.not)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setTicker(msgAlert)
                .setContentText(msgText);
        //intent to fire when notification clicked on
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
        //how the person will be notified
        mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        //cancel notification when clicked in the taskbar
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());


    }
```

after applying what mentioned below: i made this 4 events:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        alertIntent.putExtra("title", "event1");
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        Intent alertIntent2 = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        alertIntent2.putExtra("title", "event2");
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, alertIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        Intent alertIntent3 = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        alertIntent3.putExtra("title", "event3");
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, alertIntent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        Intent alertIntent4 = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        alertIntent4.putExtra("title", "event4");
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal4.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4, alertIntent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

and in `OnReceive`:

```
 createNotification(context,intent.getStringExtra("title"), "event", " event");
```

sometimes for the first time running the application all the events appear, sometimes the 3rd appear twice, and the first two do not appear, sometimes just the last one appear, so there is something wrong or messy in my code, 
whats the problem?

calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE,24);  
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);  
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);     
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(Calendar.DATE,24);  
        cal2.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);  
        cal2.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);  
        cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);       
        cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

        Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal3.set(Calendar.DATE,24);  
        cal3.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); 
        cal3.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23); 
        cal3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);     
        cal3.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

        Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal4.set(Calendar.DATE,24);  
        cal4.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); 
        cal4.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        cal4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);  
        cal4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);      
        cal4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass that information along with the intent while scheduling the alarm.

```
Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", 1);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

And in your `onReceive` check the value and show the notification based on that:

```
Integer notificationId  = intent.getIntExtra("Notification Key", -1);
if (notificationId == 1)
{
  // Show indipendente day
}
else
{
   // do something else
}
```

Instead of passing integer value, you can also pass the notification message and show it directly without any if...else condition.

Passing string data:

```
alertIntent.putExtra("Notification Key", "Independence day");
```

Getting string back:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("Notification Key");
// Calling the notification
createNotification(context, "title1", message, "event of today");
```

Comment: thanks alot, but i am facing something messy after applying 4 events, i edited the question above, please have a look.

Comment: @ygz82: Check the code again, you are passing alertIntent3 for both 3rd and 4th event. In my opinion instead of editing your question with new problem, you should ask it as a new question. Else the previous answers doesn't have any meaning to the new context.

Comment: thanks man,i was thinking into making a new question, but i thought that it will be a good idea to have all problems i am facing into just one post, because if anyone need to start with multiple alarms may face similar problems.

Comment: @ygz82: That's fine. I hope you got the solution to fix the issue. Happy holidays.

Comment: @"Midhun MP" i edited the alertintent, but the application is firing only the last notification(event4), i cant figure why this is happening

Comment: @ygz82: Please check the time, I hope the cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4 date is equal, in that case the notification tray shows the last fired notification data, unless you need to specify to show multiple notifications in the notification tray.

Comment: after changing the alarm into 4 different minutes(not in the same minute), the first and the 3rd appeared, without firing the 2nd the 4th event!!

Answer (score 1):

You could make different intents and make

```
intent.putExtra("title","independence day");
```

and also make a separate id for every notification you could do it like this.

```
alertIntent.putExtra("id", 1);
```

and in `onReceive` change to:

```
createNotification(context, intent.getStringExtra("title"), "event", " event",intent.getIntExtra("id", 0));
```

and the method

```
 public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert,int id) {
```

//your code and change this line bellow

```
    mNotificationManager.notify(id,mBuilder.build());
}
```

so it will look like this:

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    alertIntent.putExtra("title", "event1");
    alertIntent.putExtra("id", 1);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    Intent alertIntent2 = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    alertIntent2.putExtra("title", "event2");
    alertIntent2.putExtra("id", 2);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, alertIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    Intent alertIntent3 = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    alertIntent3.putExtra("title", "event3");
    alertIntent3.putExtra("id", 3);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, alertIntent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    Intent alertIntent4 = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    alertIntent4.putExtra("title", "event4");
    alertIntent4.putExtra("id", 4);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal4.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4, alertIntent4, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Comment: thanks alot, but i am facing something messy after applying what you mentioned, i edited the question above, please have a look.

Comment: thanks alot, but i am facing something messy after applying what you mentioned, i edited the question above, please have a look.

Comment: as @ygz82 say you use the same intent for the 4th one. and about the problem that sometimes the  first 2 not appear what is the time set in cal and cal 1 and so on? maybe it plain still didn't reach that time?

Comment: i check them,now only the 1st and the 3rd were appeared

Comment: are you sure you didn't change the key in the putExtra method in the 2nd and forth? It have to be spelled exactly the same.

Comment: what do you mean by change the key?

Comment: All putExtra has the key "title", so no i didn't changed it

Comment: Make a log statement in the onRecive Log.d("test",intent.getStringExtra("title")) ;and see if it  hit everything.

Comment: In   mNotificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build()); you need to make different I'd 0 1 and so on.

Comment: doing this made event2 and event4 just appear, each one 4 times at a once

Comment: i copy your code to test and i add alertIntent.putExtra("id",1);alertIntent1.putExtra("id", 2); and so on and i set the id here mNotificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build()); to mNotificationManager.notify(intent.getIntExtra("id", 0),mBuilder.build()); and it worked perfect all 4 notifications.

Comment: okay, why you used more than alertintent? and when writing mNotificationManager.notify(intent.getIntExtra("id", 0),mBuilder.build()); i noticed that "intent" is not recognized

Comment: and please , in case it worked, edit your answer by writing the code you tested

Comment: thanks alot, i tried it, at cal3 time, event1 and event 3 fired skipping event2, and event 4 fired normally, cant figure out why!!

Comment: try instead of cal.getTimeInMillis() write System.currentTimeMillis()+1000 and by the next System.currentTimeMillis()+2000 to test if it works then you prob set something wrong in your cal object.

Comment: all appeared normally ,event1 appeared separately, 2 3 4 replaced each other, so do you mean the problem is in calendar set?

Comment: finally done, the problem was with API, thanks alot @"Shia G". i was testing my app on android with api 19, this api don't get set , it needs setExact, so i made if statement to check whether to use set if the api is less than 19, and setExact for 19 and above